# iOS - can't set text on button

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using Xamarin iOS, I have a button in my .xib defined as...

```
            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" enabled="NO" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="5" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO">
                <rect key="frame" x="76" y="361" width="262" height="45"/>
                <color key="tintColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                <state key="normal" backgroundImage="images/buttongold.png" title="Please Wait...">
                    <color key="titleShadowColor" red="0.5" green="0.5" blue="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                </state>
                <connections>
                    <action selector="TakePictureClick:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="7"/>
                </connections>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint id="783" firstItem="5" firstAttribute="width" constant="262"/>
                    <constraint id="784" firstItem="5" firstAttribute="height" constant="45"/>
                </constraints>
            </button>
```

I am trying to set the text on the button to show when enabled and disabled with...

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        TakePictureButton.SetTitle("", UIControlState.Normal);
        TakePictureButton.SetTitle("Please Wait...", UIControlState.Disabled);
    }
```

So if I have...

```
                TakePictureButton.Enabled = false;
```

Shouldn't the button be reading 'Please Wait...'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of that you set the `alpha` of `TintColor` to `0`. It equals to invisible.

[What is tintColor on Button](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624025-tintcolor)

> The tint color to apply to the button title and image.

So you need to modify the xib at line 3 as below

```
<color key="tintColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
```